# Calling Set / Get Methods from another Class and .java file

Tags: java

Alright, I'm trying to call setters and getters from another function that's inside another class, in another file. Here's what I'm getting, and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Bank.java

```
package Bank;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Bank
{
  public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
     final String fileName = "Bank/AcctInfo.txt";
     File accounts = new File(fileName);

     ArrayList <Object> acctInfo = new ArrayList <Object> ();
        acctInfo = setObjects(accounts);
  }

  public static ArrayList setObjects(File document) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
     ArrayList <Object> objectArray = new ArrayList <Object> ();

     Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(document);

     String blankInfo;
     String accountType;
     String customerType;
     String customerName;

     int accountNumber;

     float balance;

        int counter = 0;    

     while (fileInput.hasNext())
     {

        accountNumber = fileInput.nextInt();
        blankInfo = fileInput.nextLine();

        accountType = fileInput.nextLine();

        customerName = fileInput.nextLine();

            customerType = fileInput.nextLine();

        balance = fileInput.nextFloat();
        blankInfo = fileInput.nextLine();

            objectArray.add(new BankAccount());

            objectArray.get(counter).setAccNumber(accountNumber);

            counter++;

     }

     return objectArray;
  }
}
```

BankAccount.java

```
package Bank;

public class BankAccount extends Bank
{       
    private int accNumber;
    private String accType;
    private String cusName;
    private String cusType;
    private float bal;

    public void setAccNumber(int accountNumber)
    {
        int accNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public int getAccNumber()
    {
        return accNumber;
    }

    public void setAccType(String accountType)
    {
        String accType = accountType;
    }

    public String getAccType()
    {
        return accType;
    }

    public void setCusName(String customerName)
    {
        String cusName = customerName;
    }

    public String getCusName()
    {
        return cusName;
    }

    public void setCusType(String customerType)
    {
        String cusType = customerType;
    }

    public String getCusType()
    {
        return cusType;
    }

    public void setBal(float balance)
    {
        float bal = balance;
    }

    public float getBal()
    {
        return bal;
    }
}
```

**Errors**:

```
Bank.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
            objectArray.get(counter).setAccNumber(accountNumber);
                                    ^
symbol:   method setAccNumber(int)
location: class Object
Note: .\Bank\Bank.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

It's not completed yet, but if someone can help me through that bit, it'd be a huge help...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `ArrayList<Object>`, use `ArrayList<BankAccount>`.

`Object` is a class that doesn't have a method with the signature `setAccNumber(int)` whereas `BankAccount` does.

The `ArrayList<Object>` declaration says that you're declaring an `ArrayList` that will have `Objects` inside it; since all classes inherit from `Object`, putting instances of `BankAccount` in the list is valid, but as far as the compiler is concerned, when you refer to an element *inside* the list, it's an `Object` and only has the standard methods available to `Object`.

There are other peculiarities in your class too (e.g. in your setter methods, you declare a new variable and assign to it, inside of assigning it to a field). I would recommend revisiting your course lecture notes if available. There's an online free PDF called [Java Precisely](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.174.4736&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which is a very concise look at Java - the free version is up to Java 5 I think, but it's enough to cover the topics here.

Comment: Thanks a ton, never would have thought of it.

Comment: To be precise, List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>(); Always better to work against interfaces when declaring reference types.

Comment: +1 James, it's a good habit to get into but I think the subtlety of doing this is outside of the scope of OP's exposure to Java and OOP (as of yet).

Comment: @ataulm I agree but worth a comment I feel. Nice answer by the way!

Comment: @user2985307 please select an answer if you found one that was correct (and upvote the others that were helpful).

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing this:

```
ArrayList <Object> objectArray = new ArrayList <Object> ();
```

the list there doesn't know what the things inside are, because you said they are `Object`.

if you make that

```
ArrayList <BankAccount> objectArray = new ArrayList <BankAccount> ();
```

it should work like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the methods of `BankAccount` on the items of your `ArrayList`, you have to specify that it is a list of BankAccounts. Speficically, the line

```
ArrayList <Object> objectArray = new ArrayList <Object> ();
```

should really be

```
ArrayList <BankAccount> objectArray = new ArrayList <BankAccount>();
```

You can think of generics as specifying what you have a list of. So for the first example, you can read it as "An ArrayList of Objects." Since you don't know if they are BankAccounts or not, you don't know if you can call `settAccNumber()` on them.

For the second example, you can read it as "An ArrayList of BankAccounts." In this case you *know* that they are BankAccounts, so you know that you can call `setAccNumber()` on them.

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) a lesson on generics, since you don't seem to quite have the hang of them.

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html) the oracle documentation on them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers **correctly** suggest using `ArrayList<BankAccount>`

If (for whatever strange reason) you cannot or do not want to do it, then you need to implicitly `cast` the retrieved list element to `BankAccount` type.

Your

```
 objectArray.get(counter).setAccNumber(accountNumber);
```

will become

```
  ((BankAccount)objectArray.get(counter)).setAccNumber(accountNumber);
```

Comment: +1 for alternative approach. For OP, casting (specifying the type explicitly in parentheses) is you (the programmer) telling the compiler that you promise that the object is of that type, and therefore should treat it as such (in this case, allow the call to `setAccNumber(int)`)